# Add events threw SQL in fullcalendar script

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, fullcalendar

I am a beginner in JS and php and I tried to make an agenda with the plugin full calendar. I'm using a database with  fullcalendar.

**My table :**

```
CREATE TABLE evenement (
  id int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  title varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_bin NOT NULL,
  start datetime NOT NULL,
  end datetime DEFAULT NULL,
  url varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_bin NOT NULL,
  allDay varchar(255) COLLATE utf8_bin NOT NULL DEFAULT 'false',
  PRIMARY KEY (id)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_bin AUTO_INCREMENT=7 ;
```

**My agenda page :**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<link href='fullcalendar/fullcalendar.css' rel='stylesheet' />
<script src='fullcalendar/lib/jquery.min.js'></script>
<script src='fullcalendar/lib/jquery-ui.custom.min.js'></script>
<script src='fullcalendar/lib/moment.min.js'></script>
<script src='fullcalendar/fullcalendar.min.js'></script>
<script src='fullcalendar/lang/fr.js'></script>
<script>

 $(document).ready(function() {
  var date = new Date();
  var d = date.getDate();
  var m = date.getMonth();
  var y = date.getFullYear();

  var calendar = $('#calendar').fullCalendar({
   editable: true,
   header: {
    left: 'prev,next today',
    center: 'title',
    right: 'month,agendaWeek,agendaDay'
   },

   events: "events.php",

   // Convert the allDay from string to boolean
   eventRender: function(event, element, view) {
    if (event.allDay === true) {
     event.allDay = true;
    } else {
     event.allDay = false;
    }
   },
   selectable: true,
   selectHelper: true,
   select: function(start, end, allDay) {
   var title = prompt('Event Title:');
   var url = prompt('Type Event url, if exists:');
   if (title) {
   var start=moment(start).format('YYYY-MM-DDTHH:mm:ssZ');
   var end=moment(end).format('YYYY-MM-DDTHH:mm:ssZ'); 
   $.ajax({
   url: 'add_events.php',
   data: 'title='+ title+'&start='+ start +'&end='+ end +'&url='+ url ,
   type: "POST",
   success: function(json) {
   alert('Added Successfully');
   }
   });
   calendar.fullCalendar('renderEvent',
   {
   title: title,
   start: start,
   end: end,
   allDay: allDay
   },
   true // make the event "stick"
   );
   }
   calendar.fullCalendar('unselect');
   },

   editable: true,
   eventDrop: function(event, delta) {
   var start = $.fullCalendar.formatDate(event.start, "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
   var end = $.fullCalendar.formatDate(event.end, "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
   $.ajax({
   url: 'update_events.php',
   data: 'title='+ event.title+'&start='+ start +'&end='+ end +'&id='+ event.id ,
   type: "POST",
   success: function(json) {
    alert("Updated Successfully");
   }
   });
   },
   eventResize: function(event) {
   var start = $.fullCalendar.formatDate(event.start, "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
   var end = $.fullCalendar.formatDate(event.end, "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
   $.ajax({
    url: 'update_events.php',
    data: 'title='+ event.title+'&start='+ start +'&end='+ end +'&id='+ event.id ,
    type: "POST",
    success: function(json) {
     alert("Updated Successfully");
    }
   });

}

  });

 });

</script>
<style>

 body {
  margin-top: 40px;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 14px;
  font-family: "Lucida Grande",Helvetica,Arial,Verdana,sans-serif;

  }


 #calendar {
  width: 900px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  }

</style>
</head>
<body>
<?php //echo json_encode($title); ?>
<div id='calendar'></div>
</body>
</html>
```

**My add_events page :**

```
<?php
// Values received via ajax
$title = $_POST['title'];
$start = $_POST['start'];
$end = $_POST['end'];
$url = $_POST['url'];
// connection to the database
try {
$bdd = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=elevage', 'root', 'admin');
} catch(Exception $e) {
exit('Unable to connect to database.');
}

// insert the records
$sql = "INSERT INTO evenement (title, start, end, url) VALUES (:title, :start, :end, :url)";
$q = $bdd->prepare($sql);
$q->execute(array(':title'=>$title, ':start'=>$start, ':end'=>$end,  ':url'=>$url));
?>
```

**My update_events page :**

```
<?php

/* Values received via ajax */
$id = $_POST['id'];
$title = $_POST['title'];
$start = $_POST['start'];
$end = $_POST['end'];

// connection to the database
try {
 $bdd = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=elevage', 'root', 'admin');
 } catch(Exception $e) {
exit('Unable to connect to database.');
}
 // update the records
$sql = "UPDATE evenement SET title=?, start=?, end=? WHERE id=?";
$q = $bdd->prepare($sql);
$q->execute(array($title,$start,$end,$id));
?>
```

Can anybody tells me what's wrong with my code and why ? My problems atm are that events do not show properly in week/day views and when I try to add an event it doesnt add in the database (so disappear after an refresh). Also the time isnt displayed.

Thanks.